# How to prevent Gstreamer H265 Encoding Reduces Sharpness?

Tags: video, encoding, gstreamer, petalinux

**Hi All,**

I am encoding the video on a FPGA device (Ultrascale+ zcu7ev) on Petalinux and I decode the video in the other device on the LAN. I take the video directly from the camera using USB interface, too. When I compare the videos, USB video obviously has more sharpness. Here is the gstreamer pipeline below;

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=4 ! queue ! vtracking ! queue ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2video1convert capture-io-mode=4 output-io-mode=5 ! video/x-raw ,format=NV16,width=$3,height=$4, framerate=30/1 ! omxh265enc loop-filter-mode=enable loop-filter-beta-offset=-3 loop-filter-tc-offset=-3 num-slices=24 periodicity-idr=240 cpb-size=500 gdr-mode=horizontal initial-delay=100 control-rate=2 prefetch-buffer=false target-bitrate=$2 gop-mode=low-delay-p ! video/x-h265, alignment=nal ! rtph265pay ! udpsink buffer-size=80000000 host=224.1.1.1 port=$1 auto-multicast=true async=false max-lateness=-1 qos-dscp=60 max-bitrate=120000000 -v`

Here are two example screenshots. The Example1: Left:USB Video, Right:Encoded-Decoded Video and Example2: Down:USB Video, Up:Encoded-Decoded Video.

Which parameter can reduce the loss of quality in the script above?

[image: Example1: Left:USB Video, Right:Encoded-Decoded Video]

[image: Example2: Down:USB Video, Up:Encoded-Decoded Video]

Im looking for your replies.
Thanks,

**Murat**